# Passing a list's items by Reference within Vb.net application

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, collections, reference

I'd like to change the content of a list of boolean, so I passed it to a method by reference like this :

```
 Dim liste As New List(Of Boolean)
    liste.Add(lbl1.Visible)
    liste.Add(lbl2.Visible)
    RaiseEvent rgProcS9Selection(liste, SelectedIndex)
```

in the method :

```
    Private Sub rgProcS9SelectionMethod(ByRef ComposantsVisibility As List(Of Boolean), ByVal SelectedIndex As Integer)
            ComposantsVisibility.Clear()
            If SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                For index As Integer = 0 To 1
                    ComposantsVisibility.Add(False)
                Next
            Else
                For index As Integer = 0 To 11
                    ComposantsVisibility.Add(True)
                Next
            End IF
End Sub
```

the content values of the list are changed but the visiblity of the labels (lbl1, lbl2) is still the same.

1. So, I need to know why the items aren't passed by reference?
2. How can I fix my code

Comment: because list contents Bools not labels.  the fact that you stored Bool values which *just happen* to originate from some labels, doesnt create a link with the label.  your list contains bool values not label objects

Comment: Why do you even expect that the labels switch their visibility just because you're changing some `bool`s in a list from `false` to `true`? It's the same as if you'd expect that your cars starts when you start the  grass cutter because both run with fuel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `two` lists. One for the *visibility* and one for the *labels*:

```
Dim liste As New List(Of Boolean)
Dim listeL As New List(Of Label)
liste.Add(lbl1.Visible)
liste.Add(lbl2.Visible)
listeL.Add(lbl1)
listeL.Add(lbl2)
RaiseEvent rgProcS9Selection(liste, listeL, SelectedIndex)
```

and in the end of `rgProcS9SelectionMethod`:

```
Private Sub rgProcS9SelectionMethod(ByVal ComposantsVisibility As List(Of Boolean), ByVal ComposantsLabels As List(Of Label), ByVal SelectedIndex As Integer)
    ...
    ...
    For i = 0 To ComposantsLabels.Count - 1
        ComposantsLabels(i).Visible = ComposantsVisibility(i)
    Next
End Sub
```